# Android launcher menu button

Tags: android, menu

I am developing a Launcher app. I need to detect when the user clicks on the menu button so I display several options (a menu). Well, I found out that there are many devices that don't have a menu button so my app cannot display the menu. Searching in other threads I saw that the solution was to have an Action Bar. This can be good for apps but not for my launcher. Anybody has any hint about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Well, I found out that there are many devices that don't have a menu button so my app cannot display the menu

More importantly, there will be very few devices with an off-screen MENU button going forward, as Google is being more stringent about this with device manufacturers.

> Anybody has any hint about this?

Create your own menu UI, opened by your own `ImageButton` or whatever.

Or, add the action bar to your activity and use it.

Comment: How would Google let the users open the menu in the built-in android launchers?

Comment: @Ton: They simply don't have a menu. You could tell this by looking at the launcher on the Android emulator. The only thing the stock Android launcher has that is more or less a menu is a context menu, triggered via a long-tap on the wallpaper, and that is simply to configure the wallpaper. *You* decided that you wanted a menu. *You* decided that you didn't want an action bar. Now *you* have to decide how to implement your own menu UI. ["Say Goodbye to the MENU Button"](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html) was written over two years ago, after all.